# curl function return Protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, http, curl

im facing here a problem with this function :

```
function curl_function($uri) 
{    
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    $timeout = 30; //set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'mycoreg');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $errornum      = curl_errno($ch);
    $info          = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $status        = (int) $info['http_code'];
    if ($errornum !== 0) {
        echo 'Error: ', curl_error($ch);
        $file_contents = NULL;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $file_contents;
}
```

It gives the error that

```
"http protocol is not supported or disabled".
```

plz need help.
thanks.

Comment: very strange error, are you sure that `https` is not supported instead of `http` ???

Comment: ooops , i've just found the problem , it was a space before http in my url.

Answer (score 3):

Debug print your URL and ensure it contains no extraneous characters.

In my case, the URL I was using with php curl was quoted. The quote is not printed by curl error handling, so the error is rather confusing and hard to track down.

You can generate this error with the following code:

```
// wrong
$uri = "'". "http://www.google.com/" . "'"; // quoted string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Now try it with the proper URL format...

```
// right
$uri = "http://www.google.com/"; // correct format URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your function like this to avoid a strange errors :)

```
function curl_function($uri) {
    $uri = trim($uri); 
    // ... your code  
}
```